# Does SE allow groups to follow users

Tags: support, feature-request, user-accounts, help-center

I think this could possibly go against the philosophy of SE, but are you able to adjust setting to follow particular users: when they post and answer questions etc? Is this something that could be set up by the moderators?

Why? / why not?

Comment: an easy way to work this out is to make a tag for that user (with their permission), and assign it as your favorite tag.

Comment: Thank you @WYSIWYG also found out you can RSS feed people but I'm looking for a good rss app

Comment: RSS apps: what OS do you use. I use liferea on Linux. RSSowl is also good. I have also used a terminal based RSS reader called newsbeuter (quite decent)

Comment: Not really an issue, but if someone was following one user, his/her voting may be biased, or at least tend to rank abnormally high percentages toward that user.

Answer (score 4):

Found out you can rss subscribe users (link at bottom right on profile page). Looking for a good rss app. The ones I've come across are too spamy

Comment: Just remember, ***always*** vote on the question/answer, ***never*** on the user. I just voted to delete a link-only answer from the [highest-rep user](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) (yes, it's really that high) on Stack Overflow the other day, because it was a bad answer, and went against site rules. Granted, he wrote it in 2009, when the rules were different, but it wasn't following today's rules. If you think a certain person usually makes worthwhile contributions to the site, and want to see all of them, that's fine, but don't vote just because it's that person.